# Sip-client which has command-line interface

Tags: command-line, sip

Is there any SIP-client for Ubuntu which has command-line interface? So, for example, I can make calls without using any GUI, just sending commands to the application.

Answer (score 7):

There are lot of sip clients which support command-line.

Pjsua is a sip client. check this for [features of pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm)

You can download pjsua from [here](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this
https://docs-new.sipthor.net/w/sip_clients/sip_session/
from https://sipsimpleclient.org/

You only need to install sudo apt-get install sipclients

Check out the repos here: https://docs-new.sipthor.net/w/debian_package_repositories/

Answer (score -2):

you can do this with skype.  see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480465/what-is-the-correct-com-skype-usage-with-linux

try:

```
skype --callto echo123
```

Comment: Skype does not support SIP, so not really an answer to the OP.

Comment: @Guss  it does answer the question of dialing from CLI...

Comment: Please read the question again - it starts: "Is there any **SIP-client** for Ubuntu..."

Comment: @Guss please read the content and consider two points.  fact:  someone voted the silly answer up (you can cancel that out, of course) -- potentially that was the OP.  Second, consider the x/y problem and the stated question.  Whatevs.