# Does skype still have a man page?

Tags: command-line, skype, documentation, manpage

Skype [used to have](https://askubuntu.com/a/492115/45156) a man page.  Now, I just get:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ man skype
No manual entry for skype
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
thufir@mordor:~$
```

I installed as per the [directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) for Ubuntu 15.10.  See also:

http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/man-skype/m-p/4321762

Comment: How do any of the links prove skype ever had a man page? As fas as I know 3rd party apps (especially those owned by Microsoft) never have man pages(?) And it is the responsibility of that 3rd app owner to provide a help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure many third party apps have man pages. There's nothing to stop the installer adding a man page as part of its install process. But it seems unlikely that it would be a priority for Skype to create and maintain a man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but for a list of all options one can use with it, `skype --help` still works:

```
Skype 4.3.0.37

Usage: skype [options]
Options:
  --dbpath=<path>       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                        Default: ~/.Skype
  --resources=<path>    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                        Default: /usr/share/skype
  --secondary           Start a secondary instance of Skype.
  --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
  --callto <nick>
  skype:<nick>?<action>
                        These commands allow Skype links handling.
  --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
  --version             Display version information and exit.
```

Comment: leaving open for a bit to see if anyone comes up with some incredible info.  thanks for the answer.